# Accessing vector<vector<int>> elements

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

I have defined:

```
const  vector<vector<int>> *ElementLines::Quad4 = new vector<vector<int>>
{
    { 0, 1 },
    { 1, 2 },
    { 2, 3 },
    { 3, 0 }
};
```

Later on, I want to iterate over that collection, to which an object is pointing:

```
for (int j = 0; j < e->LinesIndices->size(); j++)
        {
            int n1Index = e->LinesIndices[j][0]; //I expect 0 (for j = 0)
            int n2Index = e->LinesIndices[j][1]; //I expect 1 (for j= 0)
        }
```

The code above won't compile:

```
no suitable conversion function from "const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>" to "int" exists
```

But if I add `LinesIndices[j][0][0]` it indeed delivers an int. I don't quite understand what is happening here. To access a vector I just use one pair of square brackets `[i]`, is it different for this nested vector of vectors? (I would expect to be able accessing the contents by using two pairs of square brackets).

Comment: You have a pointer to vector of vector of int. You are indexing into the pointer, not the top-level vector.

Comment: @hlt I'm was not able to figure out my issue with your hint. Obviously I lack of basic knowledge. Could you show what would be the correct syntax to access the contents of the internal vectors?

Comment: Writing up a proper answer, give me a minute ;)

Comment: I guess that I should access the pointed value of LinesIndices item before trying to access it's contents: 'int n1Index = (*e->LinesIndices)[j][0];' Is this what I should be doing?

Comment: @Sturm  What is e and LinesIndices and how are they related to Quad4?

Comment: e it is an instance of a type that has a member called LinesIndices which is indeed a pointer to vector<vector<int>>

Comment: BTW, you probably want `vector<vector<int>>` without pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not compiling because your `e->LinesIndices` is a `vector<vector<int>>*` (i.e. a pointer).

In C++, as in C, you can use array notation on pointers—[`a[index]` is equivalent to `*(a + index)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a). If your pointer pointed to the first element of an array, that is exactly how you would use that array. Unfortunately for you, you only have a single vector allocated via `new`. Accessing that pointer via `e->LinesIndices[j]` is a Very Bad Thing if `j` is not 0 (because you access a vector where there is no actual vector).

There is two ways to fix this. If you really want to keep your vector on the heap, allocated via `new` (I hope you `delete` it at some point!), you could dereference the pointer before accessing it:

```
for (int j = 0; j < e->LinesIndices->size(); j++)
{
    int n1Index = (*e->LinesIndices)[j][0];
    int n2Index = e->LinesIndices[0][j][1]; // This would work too, but I wouldn't recommend it
}
```

However, the data in your vector is already on the heap. Allocating a `std::vector` via `new` is something that is—in my personal experience—very rarely necessary, and if it is not necessary for you to have a pointer here (which will heavily depend on the context you use it in), I would suggest directly creating the vector (with no pointer). If you choose this method, you will need to use `e->LinesIndices.size()` instead of `e->LinesIndices->size()`.

Comment: `*` should be inside parent.